# When I update database, information doesn't get inserted, when I insert ..... vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I GOT a big problem.

When I update my database, the information doesn't get inserted into the database. But when I insert the information into the database, it doesn't update.

This is the code that I use when I update the database trying to insert but it doesn't work, only updates:

```
 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\311026\Documents\PAP3\Biblio.accdb"
   connString = provider
   myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
   myConnection.Open()
   Dim str As String

   str = "Insert into Livrosrequisitar([NomeLivro], [AutorLivro], [EditoraLivro], [AnoLivro], [Nome_Aluno], [Ano_Aluno], [Turma_Aluno], [Contacto_Aluno], [Email_Aluno], [DataRequicicao], [RetornoRequicicao]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomeLivro", CType(TextBox11.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AutorLivro", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("EditoraLivro", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AnoLivro", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Nome_Aluno", CType(TextBox10.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Ano_Aluno", CType(TextBox9.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Turma_Aluno", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contacto_Aluno", CType(TextBox13.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email_Aluno", CType(TextBox12.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DataRequicicao", CType(DateTimePicker1.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("RetornoRequicicao", CType(DateTimePicker2.Text, String)))

   cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Livrosescola SET Quantidade = Quantidade - 1 Where NomeLivro like'%" & ListBox1.SelectedValue & "%'", myConnection)
   ListBox1.Refresh()

   Try
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       cmd.Dispose()
       myConnection.Close()
       TextBox11.Clear()
       TextBox4.Clear()
       TextBox5.Clear()
       TextBox6.Clear()
       TextBox10.Clear()
       TextBox9.Clear()
       TextBox8.Clear()
       TextBox13.Clear()
       TextBox12.Clear()
       TextBox9.Clear()

       MessageBox.Show("Registo inserido!", "Registo inserido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("Erro!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
   End Try

   listbox()
```

That is the code that I use when I insert the information, trying to update, but only inserts the code.

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\311026\Documents\PAP3\Biblio.accdb"
   connString = provider
   myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
   myConnection.Open()
   Dim str As String

   str = "Insert into Livrosrequisitar([NomeLivro], [AutorLivro], [EditoraLivro], [AnoLivro], [Nome_Aluno], [Ano_Aluno], [Turma_Aluno], [Contacto_Aluno], [Email_Aluno], [DataRequicicao], [RetornoRequicicao]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)


   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomeLivro", CType(TextBox11.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AutorLivro", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("EditoraLivro", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AnoLivro", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Nome_Aluno", CType(TextBox10.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Ano_Aluno", CType(TextBox9.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Turma_Aluno", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contacto_Aluno", CType(TextBox13.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email_Aluno", CType(TextBox12.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DataRequicicao", CType(DateTimePicker1.Text, String)))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("RetornoRequicicao", CType(DateTimePicker2.Text, String)))



   Try
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       cmd.Dispose()
       myConnection.Close()
       TextBox11.Clear()
       TextBox4.Clear()
       TextBox5.Clear()
       TextBox6.Clear()
       TextBox10.Clear()
       TextBox9.Clear()
       TextBox8.Clear()
       TextBox13.Clear()
       TextBox12.Clear()
       TextBox9.Clear()

       MessageBox.Show("Registo inserido!", "Registo inserido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("Erro!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
   End Try

   cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Livrosescola SET Quantidade = Quantidade - 1 Where NomeLivro like'%" & ListBox1.SelectedValue & "%'", myConnection)
   ListBox1.Refresh()

   listbox()
```

I want to do the same thing at the same time, but it doesn't work...

If you could help me...

Thank you!

Comment: You have an useless try catch. If you really want to catch the exception then print out the message otherwise you never know what is wrong. _MessageBox.Show("Error: "  & ex.Message, ...._ and then tell us what is the error message received

Comment: You have forgot to call ExecuteNonQuery on the Insert part of your code.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the ex.message tip, i totally forget. Also, the executenonquery worked. Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command need to be executed to do anything.

In both examples of your code you call ExecuteNonQuery only for one of the command text and not for the other.

In the first example just add this line:

```
......
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

Try
    ' Add this (and move the start of the Try catch before this line'
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomeLivro", CType(TextBox11.Text, String)))
    ....
Catch ex as Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
End Try
```

In the second example you have the same problem, but the ExecuteNonQuery is missing after the last OleDbCommand creation

Comment: Steve, i know this is odd, however i just want to give you a shout out, i always enjoy reading your answers :)